# How to copy an existing File in internal memory to external memory?

Tags: android, memory, external, file-transfer, internal

I am trying to copy a file from the applications internal memory to external memory(SD) card. I have a few doubts:

1. How do I get the location of an existing file in internal memory? if the name is x.txt would it be:

   ```
   getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"x.txt" its directory?
   ```

   So do I just do File file_source=new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"x.txt"); ?
2. I know I want the new file to be placed in the external memory so can I use this

   ```
   String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

           if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
           {
               Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "SD card detected");



           stopSensorService();

               Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "stopSensorService for file transfer");

               //make the timestamp the file name
               long TS = System.currentTimeMillis();
               StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

               stringBuilder.append(TS);
               stringBuilder.append(".txt");

               String file_name = stringBuilder.toString();

               //file name stored in file_name

               ***File file_ext = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                       Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),file_name);***
              // attempt to create this new directory
               if (!file_ext.mkdirs()) {
                   Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Directory not created");
               }
   ```

Here:

```
File file_ext = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),file_name);
```

I am trying to create a new file where I can paste the contents of existing file with name of the file as the time of system. I am not sure from here how I will paste the contents of existing internal file to this new external one. I tough I could use filechannel.transferto but I am not sure how to.

I have tried out loads of methods now I just seem to be confused.

Thank you

EDIT:

I have made the following changes to my code but it doesnt seem to give me a file in the sd card

```
View.OnClickListener export_handler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
            {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "SD card detected");



            stopSensorService();

                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "stopSensorService for file transfer");

                //make the timestamp the file name
                long TS = System.currentTimeMillis();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                stringBuilder.append(TS);
                stringBuilder.append(".txt");

                String file_name = stringBuilder.toString();

                //file name stored in file_name


                File file_ext = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),file_name);


// attempt to create this new directory


//read from sensorLog.txt file
                try
                {
                    file_ext.createNewFile();

                    FileInputStream read_file = openFileInput("sensorLog.txt");


                //read contents of internal file
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(read_file);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("Timestamp of export to SD"+TS+"/n");
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                BufferedWriter bufWr = null;

               bufWr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file_ext, false));



                // Write header
                bufWr.append(sb.toString());
                inputStreamReader.close();
                bufWr.close();
                read_file.close();


                //delete sensor file once exported
                getApplicationContext().deleteFile("sensorLog.txt");
            }

                catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: It should be .getFilesDir()+"/x.txt" And you can check if the file exists with File:exists(). Do not use mkdirs() on a file. Only for a directory and check first if the directory exists. Pasting is something a user of your app does. You want to copy a file. There are numerous examples for copying files on this forum.

Comment: Thank you.I have made some changes to the code. I am getting confused with the different ways of approaching this. I cant seem to get the file in the external storage.

Comment: You are not checking if "sensorLog.txt" exists. You are not implementing catch{}. Place a e.printStackTrace() in it so you will know if there is a catch.  "deleteFile("sensorLog.txt");" ?? I would comment that statement until I knew that the file was copied...

Comment: I checked if it exists and I also made the other change you mentioned.I for some reason am not able to get the file on SD.Should I paste the stacktrace?

Comment: Then adapt your code accordingly. Please give full path of source and destination file. Are there errors? Then place stacktrace. Log.d() all lines read to see what's going on.